# HTML nav tag does not cover the whole top

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

At first, the `<nav>` tag was not displayed in full width and not displayed at the very top.
I found out that I need to add `margin: 0` to the body in the CSS to display it in full width.

How to push the `<nav>` tag to the very top?

I expected that the `<nav>` tag would be displayed in full width at the very top as default. **Why is it not?**

```css
body {
  background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: darkgrey;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#todo {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.411);
}

#list {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>
    <span id='todo'>TODO</span><span id='list'>List</span>
  </h1>
</nav>
```

Comment: not a solution - but a comment - you should look at the semantic role of the h1... it seems as if its used here as more of a wrapper - it should present the most important information on the page - if you need a wrapper - use a div / span or other html element.

Comment: thanks a lot! That makes sense to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `<h1>` inside your nav has margin by default.

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If these styles are not "reset," you will see undesired styles/outcomes and things breaking. Its eternally suggested to "reset" the browser's styles.
Have a glance at this articles:
http://sixrevisions.com/css/should-you-reset-your-css/
[http://web.simmons.edu/~grovesd/comm244/notes/week4/css-reset](http://web.simmons.edu/%7Egrovesd/comm244/notes/week4/css-reset)

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS reset at first or on the first line of the CSS file say the margine

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)